# iframe replacement

Tags: ajax, iframe, sidebar

I need to make a page with a sidebar on the left, and a search page on the right. I need to be able to perform a search and have the results appear without refreshing the content in the chat frame on the left. Ideally, I need these pages to be able to talk to each other so that a link from the frame on the left can invoke a search on the right. Right now I'm using PHP to handle the search functionality on the right, but I can use any language really.

I looked at iframes, but I was really hoping to have the "search" page be the main page so that the scrollbar in the browser reflects the position on the search page.

I also thought maybe this could be done with AJAX, but since my search box is a form, I wasn't sure how to pass parameters to the page that shows the results.

Hopefully this makes sense, I'll clarify what I can. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use ajax. Consider [jQuery](http://jquery.com):

**HTML Search Form**:

```
<form id="searchForm">
 <input name="searchterm" />
 <input type="submit" value="Search" >
</form>
```

**HTML Search Results Container**:

```
<div id="searchResults"></div>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$('#searchForm').on('submit', function(e) {
    var $form = $(this);
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $.ajax({
        url     : '/path/to/search.php',
        type    : 'post',
        data    : $form.serialize(),
        success : function (data) {
            $('#searchResults').html(data); // or parse out your data into HTML if it isnt already sent that way
        }
    });
});
```